# Does anyone know how to change request header User-Agent value in manifest_version V3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to change the request header User-Agent value when I do `fetch` in `background.js`. Could anyone help ?
thanks in advance.

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  const RULE = {
    id: 1,
    condition: {
      initiatorDomains: [chrome.runtime.id],
      requestDomains: ['www.example.com'],
      resourceTypes: ['main_frame'],
    },
    action: {
      type: 'modifyHeaders',
      requestHeaders: [
        {header: 'User-Agent', operation: 'set', value: 'myAgent'},
      ],
    },
  };
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [RULE.id],
    addRules: [RULE],
  });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
          {
            "name": "My APP",
            "version": "0.1.0",
            "description": "My APP",
            "permissions": ["storage", "tabs",  "webRequest", "cookies", 
            "webNavigation",
            "webRequest",
            "declarativeNetRequest",
            "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess",
            "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
           ],
            "background": {
              "service_worker": "background.js"
            },
            "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
            "content_scripts": [
              {
                "matches": ["https://*/*"],
                "js": ["contentScript.js"]
              }
            ],
            "action": {
              "default_icon": {
                "16": "assets/ext-icon.png",
                "24": "assets/ext-icon.png",
                "32": "assets/ext-icon.png"
              },
              "default_title": "My APP",
              "default_popup": "popup.html"
            },
            "manifest_version": 3
        }
```

**Update:**
update requestDomains to an array.

Comment: Your code is almost correct - requestDomains must be an array too. Note there's a bug in devtools: it doesn't show the modified headers, so to verify the result use an external tool like Fiddler, Charles, or WireShark.

Comment: HI @wOxxOm, thank you. I had changed requestDomains as an array. 

it seems it works in contentScript.js, but for `background.js`, the 'User-Agent' does not change. Could you help ?

Comment: Did you verify it using an external tool as suggested in my comment?

Comment: yes. I used `fetch` to send the request. will this be related ?

Comment: yes. I understand. I had verified it by Charles, and also checked the sent request on the server side. My question is that I am not sure whether the way I sent the request matters. I used `fetch` to send the request.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** In case it's useful, it's possible to change the `User-Agent` request header in Chromium DevTools using the "Network Conditions" tab. If you want the ability to alter arbitrary request headers (just like it's possible to [alter response headers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overrides/#override-headers) with 'local overrides' in DevTools), star [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1469512).

---

The following code works for me - it allows you to add/modify any header for all requests.

### manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Header Modifier",
    "description": "Extension to modify headers for .foo.example domain",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "declarativeNetRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "*://*.foo.example/"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": {
      "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
    }
}
```

### background.js

```js
const allResourceTypes = Object.values(chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType);

console.log(allResourceTypes);

const rules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    priority: 1,
    action: {
      type: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType.MODIFY_HEADERS,
      requestHeaders: [
        {
          operation: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.HeaderOperation.SET,
          header: 'My-Custom-Header-Name',
          value: 'my-custom-header-value',
        },
      ]
    },
    condition: {
      urlFilter: '*://*.foo.example/*',
      resourceTypes: allResourceTypes,
    }
  }
];

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  removeRuleIds: [1], // remove existing rule with ID 1
  addRules: rules
});
```

**However**, it doesn't seem to be working for WebSocket (`wss://`) requests/connections. If anyone works out the problem there, please add a comment.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work for websocket with cookie header.